# putty send command via a script and capture the output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, putty, plink

We have a service that we can connect via putty over telnet. I am trying to automate a process for which I need to connect to service and execute / capture command(s) and then exit - however the issue is that that server expects a '\r\n' keystroke immediately after connect / before it takes any command as input:

```
c:\test>putty.exe -load mysession -m .\commands.txt
```

I tried many ways but I was unable to do so thru commands.txt

Is there a way we can say send ENTER key via a script to putty?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious thing and put a carriage return character followed by a line feed character `'\r\n'` at the start of the `commands.txt` file?

Comment: If you are trying to automate a `TELNET` session, I would advise you use Albert Yale's Telnet Scripting Tool.